# getting an attachment from a Outlook mail in linux

Tags: python

I would like to get  a file attached to an email I receive using Outlook.

I need to run this python script in a Linux Box.

I read about the win32com.client library.

Do you know if it works also for Linux?

If not do you know any alternative if there are?

Comment: Need some clarification. Are you trying to grab the email from Outlook, or the server it's pulling from? The latter is trivial with the right libraries, either Python IMAPLIB or POPLIB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coincidentally, today I posted an example of retrieving attachments over IMAP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230037/how-to-fetch-an-email-body-using-imaplib-in-python/2230571#2230571), it may be of some use to you.

Outlook is an email client, it may use one or more of a variety of protocols (MAPI,POP,IMAP) to access your mailbox. Your mail may be stored on the server, or it may be stored on your computer (more likely when using POP).