# Python - Forward IMAP Email with Attachments (imaplib, smtplib)

Tags: python, email

I'm having trouble forwarding mail with attachments. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm guessing it's in the Fetch statement but am unsure.

```
import sys
import uuid
import re
import smtplib
import email

address = ''
username = ''
password = ''

def checkMail():
    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(address)
    M.login(username, password)
    M.select("INBOX", readonly=True)
    typ, data = M.search(None, 'Unseen')

    messageCount = len(data[0].split())    
    print('messageCount: %', messageCount)
    if messageCount > 0:     
        for num in data[0].split():
            typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(BODY[TEXT])')
            foundAt = data[0][1].find('Content-Type: application')
            if(foundAt > 0):
                print('attachmentfound')
                sendMail(data[0][1])


    M.close()
    M.logout()       


def sendMail(raw_message):

    toAddress = ''
    fromAddress = ''
    LOGIN    = ''
    PASSWORD = ''


    server = smtplib.SMTP('', 587)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(fromAddress, toAddress, raw_message)
    server.quit()

def main():
    checkMail()

main()
```

Comment: You might want to check out [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) (alleviates a lot of the frustrations of using imaplib)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use imaplib, why not just fetch the whole message (RFC822)?  See this similar SO question:

[How to fetch an email body using imaplib in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230037/how-to-fetch-an-email-body-using-imaplib-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

It was the fetch... adding a fetch for (BODY[]) did the trick.