# Extract information from Gmail with Python

Tags: python, gmail, extract, imaplib

I have come through solutions to **extract useful information from selected received emails in Gmail mailbox**.

Aim in this example is to fetch all mails sent from a newsletter providing monthly prices for petroleum. You can freely subscribe to such a newsletter on EIA website. All such newsletter arrive in same folder in my gmail mailbox, and begin with "$".

Content for emails is like that

[image]

and my objective is to write a script that fetch the 10 last such emails (last 10 months) and plot petroleum prices for the different US regions with respect to time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Python `email` library will help.

```
import email, getpass, imaplib, os, re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This directory is where you will save attachments

```
 detach_dir = "F:\OTHERS\CS\PYTHONPROJECTS"
```

Your script then asks user (or yourself) for account features

```
user = raw_input("Enter your GMail username --> ")
pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password --> ")
```

Connect then to the gmail imap server and login

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user, pwd)
```

Select one folder, you could use the whole INBOX instead

```
m.select("BUSINESS/PETROLEUM")
```

One should use `m.list()` to get all the mailboxes. Search for all emails coming from specified sender and
select the mail ids:

```
resp, items = m.search(None, '(FROM "EIA_eLists@eia.gov")')
items = items[0].split()  

my_msg = [] # store relevant msgs here in please
msg_cnt = 0
break_ = False
```

I want the last emails, so that I am using `items[::-1]`

```
for emailid in items[::-1]:

    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")

    if ( break_ ):
        break

    for response_part in data:

      if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
          msg = email.message_from_string(str(response_part[1]))
          varSubject = msg['subject']
          varDate = msg['date']
```

I want only the ones beginning with `$`

```
          if varSubject[0] == '$':
              r, d = m.fetch(emailid, "(UID BODY[TEXT])")

              ymd = email.utils.parsedate(varDate)[0:3]
              my_msg.append([ email.message_from_string(d[0][1]) , ymd ])

              msg_cnt += 1
```

I want only the N=100 last messages

```
              if ( msg_cnt == 100 ):
                  break_ = True

l = len(my_msg)
US, EastCst, NewEng, CenAtl, LwrAtl, Midwst, GulfCst, RkyMt, WCst, CA = 
[0]*l, [0]*l, [0]*l, [0]*l, [0]*l, [0]*l, [0]*l, [0]*l, [0]*l, [0]*l 
absc = [k for k in range(len(my_msg))]
dates = [str(msg[1][2])+'-'+str(msg[1][3])+'-'+str(msg[1][0]) for msg in my_msg]
cnt = -1

for msg in my_msg:

    data = str(msg[0]).split("\n")
    cnt+=1
    for c in [k.split("\r")[0] for k in data[2:-2]]:
```

Use regular expressions to fetch relevant information

```
        m = re.match( r"(.+)(=3D\$)(.+)" , c )  
        if( m == None ):
            continue 

        country, na, price = m.groups()

        if ( country == "US" or country == "USA" ) :
            US[cnt] = float(price)
        elif( country == "NewEng" ) :
            EastCst[cnt] = float(price)    
        elif( country == "EastCst" ) :
            NewEng[cnt] = float(price)  
        elif( country == "EastCst" ) :
            CenAtl[cnt] = float(price) 
        elif( country == "EastCst" ) :
            LwrAtl[cnt] = float(price)
        elif( country == "EastCst" ) :
            Midwst[cnt] = float(price)
        elif( country == "EastCst" ) :
            GulfCst[cnt] = float(price)
        elif( country == "EastCst" ) :
            RkyMt[cnt] = float(price)
        elif( country == "EastCst" ) :
            WCst[cnt] = float(price)
        elif( country == "EastCst" ) :
            CA[cnt] = float(price)
```

Plot all these curves with US prices

```
plt.plot( absc, US )

plt.plot( absc, EastCst )    
plt.plot( absc, NewEng, '#251BE0' )    
plt.plot( absc, EastCst, '#1BE0BF' )
plt.plot( absc, CenAtl, '#E0771B' )
plt.plot( absc, LwrAtl, '#CC1BE0' )
plt.plot( absc, Midwst, '#E01B8B' ) 
plt.plot( absc, GulfCst, '#E01B3F' )
plt.plot( absc, RkyMt )
plt.plot( absc, WCst )
plt.plot( absc, CA )

plt.legend( ('US', 'EastCst', 'NewEng' , 'EastCst', 'CenAtl', 'LwrAtl', 'Midwst', 'GulfCst', 'RkyMt', 'WCst', 'CA')  )
plt.title('Diesel price')
locs,labels = plt.xticks(absc, dates)
plt.show()
```

Some related interesting topics are here

[Get only new emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210737/get-only-new-emails-imaplib-and-python?lq=1)

[Fetch mail body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230037/how-to-fetch-an-email-body-using-imaplib-in-python?lq=1)

[Forward emails with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572589/python-forward-imap-email-with-attachments-imaplib-smtplib?lq=1)

[Fetch body emails in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029768/python-imaplib-fetch-body-emails-gmail)

Results are here for three areas only

[image: us prices]

Comment: I'm getting an error in the line `msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])` saying `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`

Comment: @DebdutGoswami Try using email.message_from_bytes() method instead ( since, your data from responses_part is of type bytes).

Comment: mmwahhhhh, this is useful

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it with [Red Box](https://github.com/Miksus/red-box) (disclaimer, I'm the author).

First, [configure Gmail's application password](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/config.html#gmail).

Second, get the messages:

```
from redbox import gmail

# Set credentials
gmail.username = "me@gmail.com"
gmail.password = "<PASSWORD>"

# Select an email folder
inbox = gmail["INBOX"]

# Search and process messages
msgs = inbox.search(from_="EIA_eLists@eia.gov")
```

Third, form the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for msg in msgs:
    body = msg.text_body
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        line.split("=")
        for line in body.split("\n),
        columns=["Region", "Price"]
    )
    df["Date"] = msg.date
    df["Price"] = df["Price"].str[1:].astype("float")
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Finally plot the dataframe:

```
df.pivot_table(
    index="Date", 
    columns="Region", 
    values="Price", 
    aggfunc="sum"
).plot()
```

---

To install:

```
pip install redbox pandas matplotlib
```

Links to Red Box:

- [Source code](https://github.com/Miksus/red-box)
- [Documentation](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/)