# Reading email body text using python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

I am trying to get exact text that is sent on my gmail but i am also getting someother value also, following is my code.

```
import imaplib

server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL ('imap.gmail.com', 993)
username = 'email'
password = 'pass'
server.login(username, password)
stat , content = server.select('Inbox')
stat , data = server.fetch(content[0],'(UID BODY[TEXT])')
print (data[0][1].decode())
server.close()
server.logout()
```

In this case my output is

```
--001a11443f6015ac310559254049
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

hello

--001a11443f6015ac310559254049
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="auto">hello</div>

--001a11443f6015ac310559254049--
```

But my message was only hello

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230037/how-to-fetch-an-email-body-using-imaplib-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method.

---

```
v = data[0][1].decode()
w = v.split('\n')

message = w[5]
```

---

Obviously, my message does not have any newline. But if you have them you can try this.

---

```
v = data[0][1].decode()
w = v.split('\n')

message = ''

for i in range(i-5,(len(w)-2)):
   message = message + w[i] + '\n'
```

---

I'm pretty new to Python so I don't have advanced level knowledge but right now this one works perfectly.

Hope it helps.