# Python imaplib fetch command: not working with 'RFC822' but works with 'RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From To Cc Bcc ...'

Tags: python, imap, imaplib, rfc822

This is a minimal example of fetching emails from IMAP server using [Python imaplib package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html).
(You can check [a similar source code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example) from the official documentation.)

```py
import imaplib
import email

HOST="MY_AWOSOME_IMAP_SERVER"
USER="me@awsome.domain"
PASS="awesome password"

with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=HOST, port=993) as imap:
    # Log in
    print("Logging in...")
    resp_code, resp = imap.login(USER, PASS)

    # Fetch the last two emails
    
    resp_code, mail_ids = imap.search(None, "ALL")
    print(f"Response code: {resp_code}")
    for mail_id in mail_ids[0].decode().split()[-2:]:
        print(f"-> Mail {mail_id}")
        resp_code, mail_data = imap.fetch(mail_id, '(RFC822)')
        msg = email.message_from_bytes(mail_data[0][1])

        print(f"From   : {msg.get('From')}")
        print(f"To     : {msg.get('To')}")
        print(f"Date   : {msg.get('Date')}")
        print(f"Subject: {msg.get('Subject')}")
        print()

    imap.close()
```

- This code works well when I tested it for many email servers including [gmail.com](https://gmail.com).
- But it doesn't work when I tested for my client's email server.

The engineer from my client's email provider suggests to change the second parameter in the `fetch` command.

```py
resp_code, mail_data = imap.fetch(mail_id, 'UID RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From To Cc Bcc Subject Date Message-ID Priority X-Priority References Newsgroups In-Reply-To Content-Type Reply-To)]')
```

If I replace `'(RFC822)'` with a lengthy text `'UID RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From To Cc Bcc Subject Date Message-ID Priority X-Priority References Newsgroups In-Reply-To Content-Type Reply-To)]'`, then I have this strange behaviour.

- Now the code works for my client's email server.
- But it doesn't work for other email servers including gmail.com

What does this lengthy parameter `'UID RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From To Cc Bcc Subject Date Message-ID Priority X-Priority References Newsgroups In-Reply-To Content-Type Reply-To)]'` do? A quick SO search shows [one question containing this parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2230037/1479078), but I cannot understand why this parameter works for my client but fails for other emails servers.

Can anyone explain what this is about?

Comment: That list requests five things instead of one, namely the message's UID, its size in bytes, its flags, and a part of the contents, without implicitly setting the \Seen flag. The part of the contents is some header fields. Good IMAP code uses such things, in your case I'd suggest retrieving just From, To, Date and Subject, because that's what your code *uses.* And you can skip the search("all"), all it does is return the numbers from 1 to the return value of imap.select(). 1 2 3 .... n. When you've removed the unnecessary faff, you may have removed whatever triggers the bug.

Comment: Can you go into details about how it doesn’t work?  Do you receive an error?  What does the protocol trace look like?